# Как дать ссылку на PNG картинку в коде, добавив ее в проект?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Есть код, сравнивает 2 PNG картинки.

```
            Image img11 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Pic\Etalon.png");    
            Image img12 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Pic\ForCompare.png");
            bool compare = Equality(img11, img12);
```

Как мне сослаться в коде на картинку, которую я добавил в проект?
Например, я хочу брать Etalon.png из проекта и сравнивать с другой картинкой, которую я получаю скриншотом с веб-сайта и сохраняю локально на машину.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Image img11 = Image.FromFile(@"\Pic\Etalon.png"); 
 Image img12 = Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("LoadedFile/ForCompare.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Прописать полный или относительный путь;
- Задать диапазон поиска с помощью соответствующих классов;
- Искать по имени в подпапках заданной.

Comment: Как мне, например, прописать полный или относительный путь?  
В коде я указываю путь на локальную машину, как мне указать на файл (картинку) в проекте?